# How to delete item from javascript localstorage?

Tags: javascript

I have stored item on local storage as,

```
{ cart = {"1": ['name',25],"2": ['name2',23]} }
```

If i wanna delete the info about the item which has key `2` (inside cart values) what should i do to delete it if the cart is in local storage.

Comment: Get the stringified object (aka JSON) from local storage, parse it into an actual object, remove the property

Comment: He wants to delete part of the value and not the whole value

Comment: Question needs to state that.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava it does "*I want to delete the info about the item which has key 2 (inside cart values)*"

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get data from local Storage, and convert it to `JSON`

`var dataFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(keyName));`

Then you can specify what do you want to do with data, in your case remove object key.

`delete dataFromLocalStorage[keyNameYouWantToDelete];`

return data to localStorage

`localStorage.setItem(keyName, JSON.stringify(dataFromLocalStorage));`

Answer (score 0):

You can probably set the localStorage again with the new value which doesn't have '2', like as follows -

```
const newCart = {"1":['name',25]}
localStorage.setItem('cart', newCart);
```

Answer (score -1):

With [localStorage.removeItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem):

```js
localStorage.setItem('ItemKey', 'ItemValue');
console.log(localStorage.getItem('ItemKey'));
localStorage.removeItem('ItemKey');
console.log(localStorage.getItem('ItemKey'));
```